# Reset Validity of ngModel

Tags: angularjs, reset

Recently, I had a problem with Angular form validity. I easy can to add the entry to Array with help ngModel.$setValidity, but I can't to remove it after. My html tag has a lot of valid/invalid classes. I'd tried to do the form to pristine. But it does't work. How that things to do generally? Help me please! (Sorry for my english =) if I've made a mistake somewhere.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not terribly well documented, but you can actually pass in `null` to the `$setValidity()` function in order to completely clear a validation flag.

If you want to set it to be **valid** then simply pass in `true`

```
//Reset validity for this control
this.form.firstName.$setValidity('someValidator', null);

//Or set to valid
this.form.firstName.$setValidity('someValidator', true);
```

And here is a running snippet to demonstrate this technique.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  function MainCtrl() {
    this.firstName = 'Josh';
  }
  MainCtrl.prototype = {
    setInvalid: function(ctrl) {
      ctrl.$setValidity('customValidator', false);
    },
    setPristine: function(ctrl) {
      ctrl.$setValidity('customValidator', null);
    },
  };

  angular.module('sample', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);


}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container" ng-app="sample" ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <form name="ctrl.form">
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':ctrl.form.firstName.$invalid}">
          <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" ng-model="ctrl.firstName" />
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="ctrl.setInvalid(ctrl.form.firstName)">Set Invalid</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="ctrl.setPristine(ctrl.form.firstName)">Set Valid</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is this function: link: function (scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {}
What i should to use ? for $setValidity()

Comment: I'd tried element.$setValidity("", null) and ngModel.$setValidity("",null), and did't work ...

Comment: @Heng - I guess I'm unclear of what your use case is? In that small snippet `ngModel` is the model controller. You would call `ngModel.$setValidity` directly on it.

Comment: @Heng Do you think you could expand your question to include a better example. Or perhaps create a Plunker?

Comment: Finally ! I'd did it =)) ngModel.$setPristine(); was that was needed for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function () {
    angular.module("App")
        .directive("password", password);

    function password() {

        var lastTrueRegex = {};

        var regexes = {
            week: /(?=^.{8,}$).*$/,
            pettyWeek: /(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.*\d).*$/,
            normal: /(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z]).*$/,
            prettyStrong: /(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/,
            strong: /(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?![.\n]).*$/,
            veryStrong: /(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?![.\n])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*]+).*$/
        };

        function forEach(data, callback) {
            for (var key in data) {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    callback(key, data[key]);
                }
            }
        }

        return {
            require: "ngModel",
            restrict: 'EA',
            link: function (scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {

                ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function (textValue) {

                    forEach(regexes, function (key, regex) {
                        if (regex.test(textValue)){
                            lastTrueRegex.name = key;
                            lastTrueRegex.value = true;
                        }else{
                            ngModel.$setValidity(key, null);
                        }
                    });

                    if (lastTrueRegex.name){
                        ngModel.$setValidity(lastTrueRegex.name, lastTrueRegex.value);
                        return textValue;
                    }
                });

                ngModel.$formatters.unshift(function (modelValue) {
                    //ngModel.$setValidity('strongPass', isValid(modelValue));
                    return modelValue;
                });
            }
        };
    }
})();
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="password" ng-model="textValue" password/>
</form>
```